# Navigate to the Search Results page when Back Button is clicked

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm having 2 pages. One for the search results and other for the Detailed

Visualforcepage1: GroupSearch

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Small Group Search" Columns="2" collapsible="false">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Group #"></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText value="{!SearchGrpNum}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Group Name"></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText value="{!SearchGrpName}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Recertification Year"></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:outputPanel ><apex:inputText value="{!SearchGrpYr}"/><apex:outputText value="(YYYY)"></apex:outputText></apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!GrpSrch}" rerender="thetable,msg"/>

    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"   onclick="this.form.reset();"/> 
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acctlist}" var="acc" >
  <apex:column headervalue="Group #"><apex:outputLink value="/apex/GroupDetail?id={!acc.id}" target="_top">{!acc.AccountNumber}</apex:outputLink></apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Group Name">{!acc.Name}</apex:column> 
<apex:column value="{!acc.HBC_Grp_Anniversary_Date__c}"/>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

VisualforcePage2: GroupDetail

```
<apex:commandButton value="Back to Group Search" action="{!GrpBack}"/>
```

Apex Class:

```
Public pagereference GrpBack(){
      PageReference pageRef = Page.GroupSearch;
      pageRef.setRedirect(true);
      return pageRef;         
 }
```

My requirement here is when I clicked on Back button, it should go to the previous page along with the search results displayed. How can I achieve this

Comment: try with js. <script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: i hope you did changes on vf page but not apex class because it is a js.